# How to REPLACE view in NavController with one from another Storyboard and get animated TRANSITION?

Tags: ios, view, uisplitviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

In an iPad SplitView app the Master is a Table and selecting a Master row changes the Detail pane (a bit like Settings).  I've had that working for a while.  But the design got congested, and I am splitting up the Storyboard to put each Detail scenario in its own Storyboard.

Now I can load the Detail Storyboards and construct a synthetic Segue to them with no problem. After:

```
destVC = [otherStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:VC_IDENTIFIER];
```

I invoke this method (its in a custom UISplitViewController instance that is also the SV delegate):

```
- (void) segueToVC: (UIViewController*) destVC fromSender: (id) sender
{
    if (destVC) {
        // Let destVC approve before proceeding
        if ([destVC shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:SEGUE_ID sender:sender]) {

            // get current DetailVC from the split view
            UINavigationController* detailVC =
                (UINavigationController*)[self.viewControllers lastObject];  

            // Carry any Popover button into the destination viewcontroller
            destVC.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.rootPopoverButtonItem;

            // setup a synthetic Segue to accomplish the transfer
            UIStoryboardSegue* aSegue = [UIStoryboardSegue segueWithIdentifier:SEGUE_ID
                 source: detailVC.topViewController
                 destination:destVC
                 performHandler:^(void) {
                     // Replace the Nav Stack - but without transition
                     detailVC.viewControllers = @[destVC];
                 }];

            // give destination VC a chance to do any setup
            [destVC prepareForSegue:aSegue sender:sender];

            // Execute the segue
            [aSegue perform];
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to work reliably, but it doesn't provide any transition animation.  I've tried changing to this line inside the segue performHandler:

```
detailVC.topViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destVC animated:YES];
```

But (as expected) it PUSHES onto the existing Navigation stack, rather than REPLACING it as I need to happen.  I also tried this:

```
[detailVC.topViewController presentViewController:destVC animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

That does do a Modal transition but it replaces the entire SplitView, instead of just replacing the Detail side.  (It also generates "VC not in View Hierarchy" exception after the second invocation).

I suppose I could build my own transition animation, but I feel like I'm missing something more obvious.  Suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want. Does each storyboard have several controllers which you will push onto a navigation stack, or only one? What kind of transition do you want to have?

Comment: In general the Detail StoryBoards contain multiple controllers to be pushed onto the navigation stack. Only the first is manually segued. I use regular segues on the StoryBoards for successive Pushes.  (Only changing the root of the Nav stack involves a StoryBoard change).  As for the type of of Transition animation, I'd like a choice - maybe a wipe from the top, something distinctive to cue the user it was a replace rather than a Push or Pop.

Comment: Well, there is nothing obvious you're missing -- if that's what you want, you'll have to create your own animation. You would have to anyway, even if you had just one storyboard, since you want a non-standard animation.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check. Also, I'm not sure what a standard animation would be when Replaceing a Navigation stack.

Comment: I don't think there is a standard for that. One place it (replacing one navigation stack with another) occurs routinely is when switching tabs in a tab view controller, and there's no animation there.